# How to get address of indirect calls?

Tags: assembly

I have the following instructions in assembly:

```
0x4027b0:   mov ax, 0x10
0x4027b4:   call    rcx
```

I have to reconstruct this instruction and follow the indirect calls and indirect branches. I am wondering how can I get the address stored in rcx in order to call? How can I get the return address?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I get the address stored in rcx in order to call?

Watch it in a debugger. Put a breakpoint immediately before that line.

> How can I get the return address?

Usually the return address is equal to the line after the call. But if you're confronting some code-obfuscation techniques, you'll have to watch the sub-routine step-by-step in a debugger.
(Unless you have access to sophisticated "military grade" debugging utilities, of course)